# an issue with pushing the content right and left when sidebar is open

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I got an issue with bootstrap and CSS and js the content of the page are not been pushed to the right and left when sidebar are open or close the following are the full code here is [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akkilah/Lzwk8ror/8/)  i think it's js problem i am almost sure and i am not good at, So please any edit i am working with bootstrap and html and css most of the project

UPDATE: jsfiddle is updated and menu click is working fine in my pc the issue is moving and mouse start not to copy fine

and here is an example of the same idea I am trying to make [link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html) the following is the js code

```
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
   $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
   $('.collapse').toggleClass('in').toggleClass('hidden-xs').toggleClass('visible-xs');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Initialize Tooltip
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're suffering from multiple problems because your code isn't clean. Your menu might not be working because you've misspelled "javascript.js" in your script tag, and this shouldn't be in the position it currently is either. You have some issues in your CSS too.

I'd suggest going through your files and cleaning them up, then seeing if your problems are solved.

Comment: thank you sir but the file is working fine i know i got many issue like when menu is open it go over alert pushing it and it's not 100% also window where the question is not working after clicking the menu but thank you i will try

Comment: i found the problem there was } that is unneeded the width is 100% now but i need to push the content to top